# Where can I find the definition of "eth0" in my Ubuntu 14.04 OS?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I cannot find the definition of `eth0` in either `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, but `eth0` works perfectly.

So who can tell me in which configuration file I can find the definition of `eth0`?

Answer (score 1):

The assignments for network devices should occur via what are called the persistent network rules scripts.

You may be able to find this information in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules, being sure to look for device names specified via the "NAME=" parameter, along with MAC address, device type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one possibility.  On my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, the information appears in `/etc/iftab`:

```
# This file assigns persistent names to network interfaces.
# See iftab(5) for syntax.

eth0 mac 00:0c:29:3d:c7:72 arp 1
```

The corresponding [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man5/iftab.5.html) may be useful.  Although this was a new install, an old (2008) [blog](http://bethesignal.org/blog/2008/04/16/this-is-progress-iftab-vs-udev/) hints that udev is the "newer" way:

> Apparently, the delightfully simple /etc/iftab is no longer used, replaced with the ugly and fiercely undelightful /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules. See, you can even tell from the name of the file that you’re not going to like it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s very likely NetworkManager simply uses DHCP by default for interfaces not otherwise configured. I’ll verify this claim later.

**Update:** After installing Ubuntu, no files were around and DHCP was used. After modifying some settings (set “DHCP client ID” on IPv4 tab), a file appeared in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.

Apparently, connection profiles can also appear in `~/.gconf/system/networking/connections`, but I don’t know when. Even when I deselect the option to allow others to use a profile, it’s still saved to `system-connections`.